# "Guys, don't be idiots" or "Guys, don't be an idiot"

Tags: grammar

Which one should I use if I'm talking to more than one person?

"Guys, don't be idiots". or "Guys, don't be an idiot".

I think both can be used but that's just my opinion. I'd like to hear the opinion of a native english speaker on this.

Answer (score 1):

Only the first one makes sense. That's because "Guys" is plural and idiot is singular. So, say you're talking to three different people and calling them "Guys," and telling them not to be idiots. What that means is you're saying each of them shouldn't be an idiot, which in total would be a plural of three idiots.

If, however, you said "Guys, don't be an idiot," you'd be telling all three of them not to be the same idiot--which is impossible. Only one of them can be that one idiot. The other two have to be their own version of idiots.

Is that clear?

Comment: Yes,It is.But how about the phrase : "Guys,dont be this guys" or " Guys, dont be like this guy "  you are telling a group of people  not to act like a particular guy .it's possible.

Comment: Regarding, "Guys, don't be this guys," that's not grammatically correct at all.  It should be, "Guys, don't be like those guys."

Comment: Regarding, "Guys, don't be like this guy," I'm not sure if that's gramatically correct either. Even if it is, there's a difference. Multiple people can all act *like* someone, but they cannot all *be* the same person. So you could (maybe--I'm not sure if it really is correct) say, "All of you shouldn't act like John," but you couldn't say, "All of you should not be John." There can only be 1 John.